# Can I cmd-F and click a highlighted link in Safari (or something similar) without a mouse?

Tags: safari, keyboard, customization

I'm trying to make my Mac as mouseless and possible. My three last big hurdles:

- Moving the current window to a different space in Spaces. (I'm still on OS 10.6, until 10.8 comes out.)
- A more efficient way to move through toolbars and menu bar than Tab.

And

- **When using Safari, being able to Cmd-F ("find") linked text and then click it.** (Or some better way to move through in-page links I've not thought of.)

Comment: In FF, you can set it so that typing = searching. Not need for CMD+F. So just type the link. If it isn't unique, tab or CMD+G to get to it, then hit enter.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Type-to-Navigate](http://dbergey.github.com/)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! You should submit this to Safari's extension page (unless it's there and I've not seen it).

Comment: @fakaff It's listed in the extension gallery already.

Comment: I've been using [Glims](http://www.machangout.com/) for this, but this looks better -- Glims isn't a new-style Safari extension, and it doesn't allow you to activate links from the keyboard either. (I'll be keeping Glims installed for one or two other things, though.)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>-selected text doesn't seem to be available to activate.  But you can <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>through the page's links until you've highlighted the one you want, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate it.

In Preferences | Advanced, you can reverse the <kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior so the <kbd>Tab</kbd> selects links and <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> selects window elements.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://superuser.com/questions/233246/move-windows-between-spaces-in-mac-os-x-using-only-the-keyboard there is no keyboard shortcut for moving a window to a different space.